# whitespace remove from imported project

Tags: android, android-studio, whitespace

while importing the project to Android Studio, I have this error msg ( project file should not contain whitespace, as this can cause problems with the NDK tools. )
what does this mean? and how can I solve it ?? as it gives me a lot of errors in the project!

Comment: If you're not going to use NDK (or some sort of native C++ code) it doesn't matter really.